# Discord Bot ctx only capturing first word

Tags: python, bots, discord, ctx

```
from discord.ext import commands
import random

description = '''An example bot to showcase the discord.ext.commands extension
module.

There are a number of utility commands being showcased here.'''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', description=description)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')




#here i need the help

@bot.command()
async def idea(ctx, content):
    """Repeats a message multiple times."""
    await ctx.send(content)
    f= open("supersmartidea.txt","a")
    f.write("¦" + content + "\n")
```

the bot only safes the first word entered as ctx, so if i type
?idea this is a great idea,
only "this" is getting written down.
the bot shoud write down "this is a great idea"
I never coded a bot before and cant figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible by using the following .join feature.

```
@bot.command()
async def idea(ctx, content):
    """Repeats a message multiple times."""
    message = (" ").join(content)
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could go about getting the entire content.

This will give a string of what they say. For example `?idea A good idea` will return: `A good idea`

```
@bot.command()
async def idea(ctx, *, content):
    #code
```

This will return a tuple of each word. For example: `?idea A good idea` will return: `('A', 'good', 'idea')` You could then turn this into a string by doing `content = ' '.join(content)`

```
@bot.command()
async def idea(ctx, *content):
    #code
```